# 4/21 release - change with SSJS Update Query Definition?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, query-definition

My fairly static SSJS code that updates a query definition started failing on 4/21 with no changes on my end. Was something changed that would cause this very straightforward code to return a value of "Error" for the `qd_updatestatus` variable?

I've double checked the external key and query syntax - both are good.

```
<script type="text/javaScript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1");

var QD_EligibleContent_ExternalKey = "00ec437a-e78d-4ab1-88c1-d5d94c7f21e4";
var QD_EligibleContent = QueryDefinition.Init(QD_EligibleContent_ExternalKey);

var qd_updatestatus = QD_EligibleContent.Update({
            QueryText: "SELECT TOP 1 ContentGUID FROM ContentDetails_Log cdl", TargetUpdateType: "Overwrite"
            });

</script>
```

Comment: What exactly does the error message say?

Comment: Have you verified that the source and destination DE have not been deleted or changed (including the fields inside the DE, the subscriberkey, etc)?

Comment: The code is not generating an error, rather the response on the QD Update is simply "Error" - I am expecting it to be "OK"

Comment: The DE has not been altered or deleted. I was able to manually update and save the QD in the UI exactly what I'm trying to do with SSJS.

Comment: This is being attended to today.  Please post tomorrow if this is still an issue.

Comment: Still an issue.

Comment: I'm also experiencing almost exactly this problem, except I don't get an error - it just doesn't update my query definition. @Timothy

Comment: This has been resolved. The issue stemmed from the release last weekend and affected SSJS and AMPscript functions to create or update SQL Query Activities. If you're still experiencing issues you may want to reach out to support and reference this question. :)

Comment: OK, so, I talked to the team responsible for this section of our code, and we cannot reproduce, and have wondered about your syntax.  To take this further I would need information totally beyond what is appropriate for stack exchange due  to security issues.  The team recommends you call support with an escalation request (if fixing syntax doesn't work) to get the internal teams specifically looking at your account directly.